# npm shrinkwrap complaining of missing dependencies

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-shrinkwrap

I have been building releases in my CI environment by checking out from source control, running npm install on a clean directory, followed by `npm dedupe && npm shrinkwrap`. This has been working perfectly.

Now shrinkwrap is throwing an error:

```
npm ERR! Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! missing: async@^1.4.0, required by handlebars@4.0.6
```

This isn't one of my dependencies, so must be a sub-dependency. I have tried checking this dependency into source control and it still throws the same error.

Is there a workaround for this? I would like to at least try something before having to migrate everything to yarn...

Answer (score 0):

For me updating to NPM v5 solved this issue when shrinkwrapping.

Updating to NPM v5 will also give you reproducible builds if you add your [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) to source control, which will stop your build from failing in future when sub-dependencies change.